# Save a unique order id for each company in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I would like to have a unique id_order per company, and if already exist, i cannot save the order or form is not valid. In my example, each company save orders, Company A can save id_order 1 id_order 2 id_order 3 ... Company B can save id_order 10 id_order 20 id_order 30... what i want now is that company A cannot save two times id_order 3 or company B cannot save two times id_order 20.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    last_order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)

class Order(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            Company.objects \
                .filter(pk=self.company_id) \
                .update(last_order=self.id_order)
```

Forms:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def __init__(self, company , *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['company'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.filter(name=company), initial = company)
        try:
            code = company.last_order + 1
            self.fields["id_order"].initial = code
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a unique constraint on the couple `company` and `id_order`:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_order = models.IntegerField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)

    # …

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['company', 'id_order'],
                name='unique_per_company'
            )
        ]
```

I would however *not* store the `last_order` at the company model. This might be a problem since the order ids are not per se dispatched in order, for example it is possible that the last order id is `4`, whereas there is already a `5`.

For a company you can simply calculate the maximum value and increment this with one:

```
from django.db.models import Max

class OrderForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def __init__(self, company , *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['company'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.filter(pk=company.pk), initial=company)
        code = (company.order_set.aggregate(
            max_id=Max('id_order')
        )['max_id'] or 0) + 1
        self.fields["id_order"].initial = code
```

You also might want to consider replacing the `DecimalField` with `decimal_places=0` with a [**`BigIntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield).

Comment: great ! big thks. pls is there any solution in case of already existing msg to show only error message or field already existing instead of the yellow error page with Exception Value: The Order could not be created because the data didn't validate.